# hyperledger fabric java chaincode error

Tags: java, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

i used peer chaincode deploy to run go src example, i got the right result,
then i tried the java src example, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OxMH.png)

[image]

i got a chaincode,but when i used this chaincode for query,it showed me:

```
Error: Error querying chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction
a3a350ff98660bcade4570acd507d0b380f374ea9399194b39e0301135849feb0732 - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)"
```

i use docker-tool box to create the envirement for hyperledger fabric.

Comment: can you please add more details ? are you runnning it in `dev` mode or normal mode ? how did you run the peer ? what name are you providing when you are querying ?

Comment: also you need to provide `-l java` if you are deploying it using java code

Comment: yeah, i have used -l java and -u jim, in normal mode.when -l java ,the init func return a chaincode ,but when i used the chaincode to test the query, it shows me the error,and no result. when i test query func with go src code, i can get the result.

Comment: also i change the test request, when i use the init1 (a function which the demo example doesn't have),it also give me a chaincode,it's strange.

Comment: can you please add entire code and all the errors and whatever you have tried ?

Comment: peer chaincode deploy -u jim -l java -p examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample/src/main/java/example -c '{"Function":"init","Args":["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
 the result is ok.
then the query request:
peer chaincode query -l java -u jim -n (chaincode from last step ) -c '{"Function":"query","Args":["a"]}'
the result:
Error: Error querying chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for .....
 LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)"

Comment: i am familar with java. so i want to use java.
when i test the go example, it's ok. i can transfer and query. but java is wrong. so i dount the enviroment. but i don't really know the point. i just do as the doc tells me.

Answer (score 3):

Chaincode ID is generated as hash code for multiple parameters (path to chaincode + arguments + source code )
if you see in the response for “deploy” command something like this:

```
{“jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"status":"OK","message":"8d803651564981858842409c6a5c3bf3f6ea69f90a6a7bfb672c2c8c3b6eb4c48105c5807e52f1a5ffdce0e86966688019a6c4013ffca524d5896e0b9ae201c6"}
```

It means that your request to deploy transaction is accepted. From this moment Fabric will try to create a container for your chaincode and start it in docker. In case something goes wrong and the container is not started, you will receive the following response:

```
“LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found“ for all your commands.
```

In your example you are trying to deploy Java chaincode in a GO container and as a result the response is:

```
(INFO 002 Deploy result: type GOLANG chaincodeID:...)
```

That is happening because Fabric does not use a “language” variable to detect platform type (valid for version which was available **09/09/2016**)

I managed to deploy a Java chaincode using the following REST request:

`curl -XPOST -d  ‘{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy",  "params": {"type": 4,"chaincodeID": {"path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample","language": "java"}, "ctorMsg": { "args": ["init", "a", "100", "b", "1000"] }},"id": 0}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode`

`type:4` means that this chaincode is Java and appropriate container should be used. (for GO we should use `type:1`)

Keep in mind that Java currently works with `security.enabled=false` only and with `security.enabled=true` you will see the following error message:

```
[dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 095 Error building images: API error (500): {"message":"The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty"}
```

Comment: thank you.
i try the request what you said,it shows me:
 ERRO 03e Error building images: Error: image hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64- not found
01:33:12.533 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 03f Image Output:
Step 1 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64-
Pulling repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-javaenv

but docker pull docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-javaenv  is useness.

Comment: It possible that your environment is obsolete. Can you try to checkout latest version from gerrit and rebuild peer and membersrvc services ?