# Java hyperledger chaincode deploy error in IBM Bluemix (The Dockerfile cannot be empty)

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy SimpleSample java chaincode example to IBM Bluemix blockchain through API. when I deploy, I can get the success message with chaincode ID. But in Network page I could not see chaincode ID. when I see logs, I can get the following error.

```
[dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 043[0m Error building images: API error (500): Error response from daemon: The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty
[dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 044[0m Image Output:

[dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 045[0m start-could not recreate container API error (500): Error: image library/9bbb29a5a6794936aaae6ee299a2636e-vp0-624c3384a3b6047ef189de555743206cd22f6add42f952975e94bb68ff11ec2f1205a8ce6cbb7bbedfc369939f15b6ac5ae598180138bcd4abd0b34275bfcc71:latest not found
[chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 046[0m launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: API error (500): Error: image library/9bbb29a5a6794936aaae6ee299a2636e-vp0-624c3384a3b6047ef189de555743206cd22f6add42f952975e94bb68ff11ec2f1205a8ce6cbb7bbedfc369939f15b6ac5ae598180138bcd4abd0b34275bfcc71:latest not found
```

I used the following JSON input to deploy the java chaincode in Bluemix Blockchain API.

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"deploy","params":{"type":4,"chaincodeID":{"path":"https://github.com/gobiarun/SimpleSample.git"},"ctorMsg":{"function":"init","args":["a","900","b","20000"]},"secureContext":"user_type1_0"},"id":1}
```

For testing I created new repository and copied the SimpleSample example from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample.

I am facing this issue only for Java chaincode and not for GO Lang files.
I am not sure why IBM Bluemix Blockchain throwing error for Dockerfile.
Please anyone help me to deploy the Java Chaincode in IBM Bluemix Blockchain.

(Also I tried to create Dockerfile in repository root folder as mentioned in [hyperledger fabric java chaincode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403727/hyperledger-fabric-java-chaincode-error/39413318#39413318). But still I am getting same error)

Comment: Are you using fabric 0.6 or 1.0?

Comment: I am using fabric 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Fabric 1.0.0-beta and all subsequent release candidates do not support Java chaincode. It isn't ready for production use and hence the release engineers have chosen to disable it until post 1.0.0 release, when the work will be completed. Please see the [release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta) for 1.0.0-beta.

Comment: Now I tried with both fabric 1.0 and 0.6 versions. Both versions of chaincode deployment, I am getting same error in Bluemix Blockchain "The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty". I just tried with SimpleSample which is in fabric examples. Am I missing something with deployment?